# Why doesn't git client send HTTP Basic Authorization header?

Tags: git, authorization, client, command-line-interface, basic-authentication

I've noticed the git client (CLI) doesn't actually send a `Authorization` header when you provide the username and password for a repository to clone. I'm working on a custom Git service and need the user credentials to come through to the server for validation. The problem is the git client doesn't seem to be sending the `Authorization` header at all, even when credentials are provided. I am expecting it sens a "Basic bas64encodedvalue" for the value, but not seeing it. Any ideas how I can get the git client to actually send the username & password to the server when I do a `git clone https://repohere`?

Answer (score 2):

The server wasn't responding with `WWW-Authenticate` header. After getting it to return that its working now.